# How to implement If... else structure in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here is my jsp snippet it uses spring mvc

```
 <form:select path="noOfBankDetails" id = "noOfBankDetails">
 <form:option value="0">0</form:option>
 <form:option value="1">1</form:option>
 <form:option value="2">2</form:option>
 <form:option value="3">3</form:option>
 <form:option value="4">4</form:option>
 </form:select>

 <!-- All the following divs are hidden -->
 <div id = "firstBankDetail"> 
<div id = "secondBankDetail">
<div id = "thirdBankDetail">
<div id = "fourthBankDetail">
```

Here is my jQuery snippet which shows all the divs when dropdown noOfBankDetails is changed

```
  $("#noOfBankDetails").change(function(){
           $("#firstBankDetail").show();
           $("#secondBankDetail").show();
           $("#thirdBankDetail").show();
           $("#fourthBankDetail").show();
        });
```

It works perfectly fine...  But i want to achieve something different 
Pseudo of it goes like this

```
IF noOfBankDetails IS 0 THEN 
    Show none of divs
ELSE IF noOfBankDetails IS 1 THEN 
    Show div firstBankDetail
ELSE IF noOfBankDetails IS 2 THEN 
    Show div firstBankDetail
    Show div secondBankDetail
and so on..
```

How should i go about doing this in jQuery. I am a beginner in jQuery. Please provide some guidance.

Comment: You have laid out the logic. Just convert those into jquery code line by line. Thats it.. Worry about optimization later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery `if else` is JavaScript `if else` FYI, anyways:

```
 $("#noOfBankDetails").change(function(){
  if (this.value == 0) {
      //do 0 stuff
  } else if (this.value == 1) {
      //do 1 stuff
  } else if (value == 2) {
      //do 2 stuff
  }
 });
```

Or a switch:

```
$("#noOfBankDetails").change(function(){
    switch(this.value) {
        case 0: //do 0 stuff
        break

        case 1: //do 1 stuff
        break;

        case 2: //do 2 stuff
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the switch suggestion, and saving me finishing typing up an example :)

Comment: [case-switch (in Chrome) is much slower than if-else](http://jsperf.com/switch-if-else/33) -- possibly because it's being converted into if-else statements inside the JS engine.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need jQuery for a if/elseif/else. You just can use simple Javascript:

I hope i have no errors. Should work.

```
$("#noOfBankDetails").change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();

  if(value == 0) {
    $("#firstBankDetail").show();
  }
  else if(value == 1) {
    $("#secondBankDetail").show();
  }
  else if(value == 2) {
    $("#thirdBankDetail").show();
    $("#fourthBankDetail").show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#noOfBankDetails").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
        $("#firstBankDetail").hide();
        $("#secondBankDetail").hide();
        $("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
        $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();
        $("#secondBankDetail").hide();
        $("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
        $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        $("#firstBankDetail").show();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
        $("#firstBankDetail").show();
        $("#secondBankDetail").show();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 3) {
        $("#firstBankDetail")..show();
        $("#secondBankDetail").show();
        $("#secondBankDetail").show();
    }
    //Continue the same logic below
    else if ($(this).val() == 4) {}
});
```

Comment: I think you need to check your code.  You're repeating the same actions in some of it.